# Check if each element in a numpy array at its given position matches another element at the same position in a different array

Tags: python, numpy

Given two arrays,

```
a = ([1,2,3])
b = ([1,3, 2])
```

is there an elegant way to check if any element at position i in a matches position i in b?

I know it's easy enough to loop through:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b)):
        if a[i] == b[j]:
            print("There is a match")
```

But I am interested in more elegant or faster methods.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to use `numpy`, it offers a concise, elegant, and efficient way to do this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([1, 3, 2, 4])
np.where(a==b)
```

The output is a tuple containing an array of indices where the elements of `a` are equal to the elements of `b`:

```
(array([0, 3]),)
```